# A team of 12 hall players stand in a line. How many ways are there to choose 5 players so that no 2 adjacent players are chosen?

Tags: probability, combinations

Solution provided to the question is C(8,2) but I'm not too sure why is it so. Can someone explain the solution to me? Thanks!

Comment: The answer appears to be a typographical error.  The answer should be $\binom{8}{3} = \binom{8}{5}$.

Answer (score 3):

Each admissible selection of $5$ players can be encoded as a string of length $12$ consisting of $5$ ones  and $7$ zeros with at least one zero between any two ones. Therefore we begin with the $7$ zeros:
$$\cdot0\cdot0\cdot0\cdot0\cdot0\cdot0\cdot0\cdot\quad.$$
The eight dots represent slots into each of which a single one may be inscribed. There are
$${8\choose 5}=56$$
ways to choose $5$ of the $8$ slots, and this is also the number of admissible selections.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether the answer is ${8 \choose 2}$.

Consider the $9$-people case
$$COCOCOCOC$$
where $C$ is the chosen and $O$ is the others.

Now the problem is changed into putting $3$ more $O$s to the string.

For $OOO$, there are $6$ outcomes.
For one $O$ and the other two $O$s there are ${6 \choose 2}2!$ outcomes. For three separate $O$s there are ${6 \choose 3}$ outcomes.

Add them up and you should get 56.

Answer (score 0):

The answer $\binom{8}{2}$ is a typographical error.  It should be $\binom{8}{3} = \binom{8}{5}$.

We can represent a selection as a bit string of length $12$ in which a $1$ represents a selected player and a $0$ represents a player who is not selected.  For instance, $010010010101$ means that players in the second, fifth, eighth, tenth, and twelfth positions are selected, while $010101001010$ means that players in the second, fourth, fifth, ninth, and eleventh positions are selected.

The requirement that no two consecutive players are selected means that unless the last player is selected, whenever a player is selected, the next player is not selected.  In terms of bit strings, this means that unless the last bit is a $1$, each $1$ is followed by a zero.  We consider cases:

1. The last player is not selected.  Then each player who is selected is followed by a player who is not selected.  Thus, we must have five substrings of the form $10$.  These account for ten of the twelve players (the five pairs consisting of a player who is selected and the neighbor who is not selected).  Thus, we need two additional zeros to account for the other players who are not selected.  This gives us seven objects, five bit strings of the form $10$ and two zeros.  The number of ways we can select five players such that the last player is not selected and no two consecutive players are chosen is the number of ways we can fill five of seven positions with bit strings of the form $10$, which is $\binom{7}{5}$.
2. The last player is selected.  Thus, there is a $1$ in the last position of the bit string.  Four other players are selected from the first eleven players.  Since the player following a player selected from the first eleven is not selected, we need four bit strings of the form $10$ to account for each such pairing of a selected player and the neighbor who is not selected.  These four bit strings account for eight of the eleven players before the selected last player.  Thus, we need three additional zeros to account for the other players who have not been selected.  This gives us seven objects, four bit strings of the form $10$ and three zeros.  Therefore, the number of ways four players can be selected when the last player is selected so that no two consecutive players are chosen is the number of ways we can fill four of the seven positions with bit strings of the form $10$, which is $\binom{7}{4}$.

Since these two cases are disjoint, the number of ways five of the twelve players can be selected so that no two consecutive players are selected is 
$$\binom{7}{5} + \binom{7}{4} = \binom{8}{5}$$
by [Pascal's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule).